# Minimum dimension of an array in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

Let us consider an array which could be given by AA = [1] or by AA= [1 2]. Thus, we don't know beforehand its dimensions.

We can extract the minimum dimension in Matlab using:

```
min(size(AA))
```

What commands should I use in Julia? A similar approach would lead to an error:

```
m,n=size(AA,1),size(AA,2)

minimum(m,n)
```

it seems that Julia computes the minimum of a collection and it would not see (m,n) as a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing

```
minimum(size(A))
```

just works.

`size(A)` returns a tuple which is seen as a collection.
To get the minimum of several arguments one can use `min(m,n)`.